# Drop duplicates by index, keeping max for each column across duplicates

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe, where some of the rows have duplicate indices

```
    A    B    C    D
k1  1    2    3    1
k1  2    1    1    3
k2  1    2    1    2
```

I'd like to keep the max value across each column within the duplicates:

```
    A    B    C    D
k1  2    2    3    3
k2  1    2    1    2
```

Ideas?

Comment: Can you just use `df.groupby(df.index).max()`?

Comment: df.groupby(level = 0).max() would give you the desired output. @pshep123, you can post your comment as an answer

Comment: @A-Za-z, thanks. I'm typing this from my phone, so haven't run the code, but expect it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alex, I think something as simple as:

```
df.groupby(df.index).max()
```

Should do it for you.

Comment: When I do this, my index field is strangely mutated, causing me to think groupby might be doing something odd -- I give it a string as the index and after groupby it's a datetime. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you rename that index as a column and groupby that new column? Also, did you check the dtype? Is the dataframe you're working with much different than what you posted?

Comment: @ Alex Lenail, can you post the dataframe on which you are trying this? Because this code works fine on the df you have currently posted

Comment: Sorry the data I was working with was just a little malformed. This works I think!

Comment: Glad to hear it!